# How can I use more than one asset folder in my dash app?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a dash app which needs to use 2 different css files. One is in the assets folder where the app is located, but the other one sits in a relative path, e.g under common

```
all_my_apps/
   |--app1/ 
      |--app1.py
      |--assets/
         |-- app1.css
   |--app2/ 
      |--app2.py
      |--assets/
         |-- app2.css
   |--common/ 
      |--common.css
```

I used to be able to do it (in dash 0.4.1) using static_url_path and flask.send_from_directory() which don't work anymore.

Comment: If you are still active, could you perhaps show an example code of how you performed it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try symlinking your common.css inside the app asset folders. Something like `cd app2/assets && ln -s ../../common/common.css`